# Remove Standard Quick Action from Object

Tags: permissions, list-view, quickaction

I need to remove the standard quick action on the object, but still allow users to create via LWC and custom components.

Here is a screen shot of the buttons I'm talking about:

[image: Buttons]

I'm trying to remove the `New` button, but still allow users to create through other custom actions we have in our org. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a list view for a given object. You can edit the buttons that display by editing your list view [Search Layout](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000331581&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1) for the given object.

1. Setup --> your desired object --> Search Layouts for Salesforce Classic

[image]

2. Click on the down arrow for "List View" layout and select "Edit".

[image]

3. From here, you can uncheck standard buttons. For your situation, you're interested in removing "New".

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't this be a global remove though? I want to make sure it stays for other profiles.

Comment: I didn't realize that was what you were asking? It's a global remove for List Views only. It should still be available on the records' page.